# How to display object array in tableview javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to make a javafx program.  I am supposed to make a phonebook.  I am struggling to display the phonebook with table view. It is currently saved into a text file from an array, then when the program is opened it reads the text file back into the array.  I need to put that array into the table but cant seem to do it.  here is my code, sorry for the length.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static entry[] contactList = new entry[200];
    public static int num_entries;
    public static Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

    //reads textfile into array
    public static void readPhonebook (File fileName) throws Exception{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String tempFirst, tempLast, tempNum, tempNotes, line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
            tempFirst = st.nextToken();
            tempLast = st.nextToken();
            tempNum = st.nextToken();
            tempNotes = st.nextToken();
            while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                tempNotes = (tempNotes + " " + st.nextToken());
            }
            contactList[num_entries] = new entry(tempFirst, tempLast,  
tempNum, tempNotes);
            num_entries++;
        }}

    //prints array to file
    public static void arrayToFile(File filename) throws Exception {
        PrintStream p = new PrintStream(filename);

        for (int i = 0; i < num_entries; i++) {
            p.println(contactList[i].first + "\t" +
                    contactList[i].last + "\t" +
                    contactList[i].number + "\t" +
                    contactList[i].notes);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       launch(args);
        num_entries = 0;
    }



    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStage.setTitle("PhoneBook");

        //file
        File f = new File("phonebook.txt");


        //boarder pane
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(10.0D, 20.0D, 10.0D, 20.0D));


        //buttons
        Button btnAdd = new Button("Add");
        Button btnDel = new Button("Delete");
        Button btnEnt = new Button("Enter");


       //textfields and table
         TextField tffirst = new TextField();
        tffirst.setPromptText("Enter First Name");
        TextField tflast = new TextField();
        tflast.setPromptText("Enter Last Name");
        TextField tfnumber = new TextField();
        tfnumber.setPromptText("Enter Number");
        TextField tfnotes = new TextField();
        tfnotes.setPromptText("Enter Notes");


        //more table stuff
        TableView table = new TableView();
        TableColumn firstcol = new TableColumn("First Name");
        firstcol.setMinWidth(100);
        TableColumn lastcol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
        lastcol.setMinWidth(100);
        TableColumn numcol = new TableColumn("Number");
        numcol.setMinWidth(100);
        TableColumn notescol = new TableColumn("Notes");
        notescol.setMinWidth(100);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstcol, lastcol, numcol, notescol);









        //vboxleft
        VBox vbleft = new VBox(100.0D);
        vbleft.setPadding(new Insets(5.0D, 5.0D, 5.0D, 5.0D));
        vbleft.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vbleft.getChildren().add(btnAdd);
        vbleft.getChildren().add(btnDel);


        //vboxright
        VBox vbright = new VBox(60.0D);
        vbright.setPadding(new Insets(5.0D, 5.0D, 5.0D, 5.0D));
        vbright.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vbright.getChildren().add(tffirst);
        vbright.getChildren().add(tflast);
        vbright.getChildren().add(tfnumber);
        vbright.getChildren().add(tfnotes);
        vbright.getChildren().add(btnEnt);
        tffirst.setVisible(false);
        tflast.setVisible(false);
        tfnumber.setVisible(false);
        tfnotes.setVisible(false);
        btnEnt.setVisible(false);


        //vbox center
        VBox vbcenter = new VBox(60.0D);
        vbcenter.setPadding(new Insets(5.0D, 5.0D, 5.0D, 5.0D));
        vbcenter.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vbcenter.getChildren().add(table);


        //pane stuff
        pane.setLeft(vbleft);
        pane.setRight(vbright);
        pane.setCenter(vbcenter);



        //scene stuff
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800.0D, 450.0D);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();


        readPhonebook(f);





        //sets textfields editable
        btnAdd.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                tffirst.setVisible(true);
                tflast.setVisible(true);
                tfnumber.setVisible(true);
                tfnotes.setVisible(true);
                btnEnt.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        //saves info and makes textfields not editable and shows array in gui
        btnEnt.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                String stfirst = null;
                if(tffirst.getText() != null) {
                    stfirst = tffirst.getText();
                }
                String stlast = null;
                if(tflast.getText() != null) {
                    stlast = tflast.getText();
                }
                String stnumber = null;
                if(tfnumber.getText() != null) {
                    stnumber = tfnumber.getText();
                }
                String stnotes = null;
                if(tfnotes.getText() != null) {
                    stnotes = tfnotes.getText();
                }
                contactList[num_entries] = new entry(stfirst, stlast,  stnumber, stnotes);
                num_entries++;
                try{
                    arrayToFile(f);
                } catch(java.lang.Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Error: File not saved.");
                }
                tffirst.clear();
                tflast.clear();
                tfnumber.clear();
                tfnotes.clear();
            }
        });

    }

}
class entry {
    public String first, last,  number, notes;
    public entry(String stfirst, String stlast, String stnumber, String stnotes) {
        first = stfirst;
        last = stlast;
        number = stnumber;
        notes = stnotes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own question. By deleting all the code, you have made this question meaningless, and made the answers irrelevant for other users. You could certainly use to reduce the amount of code, by creating a [MCVE], but deleting it entirely means the question is no longer of any use to anyone else.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403803/

Answer (score 1):

There are several things in your program that should be fixed or could be improved:

1. According to the java naming conventions classes start with uppercase letters.
2. **Using an fixed size array:**
   This limits the number of entries an you need to keep track of the filled entries. You could simply use a `List<Entry>` instead.
3. `TableColumn`s require `cellValueFactory`s to display contents in a column. Otherwise they remain empty.
4. `StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that should not be used. Use `split` instead. This makes things simpler btw since you can simply impose a limit on the number of elements instead of concatenating the last matches yourself.
5. File readers and writers should be closed as soon as you're done with them.
6. You need to actually insert the entries to the `TableView`'s items list.
7. You don't need to write rewrite the file completely from scratch when adding a new entry to the end. Simply write a single entry in append mode.
8. Take care of empty lines. You inevitably get one, if you implement the *remove* functionality later.
9. Passing data via `static` fields should be avoided, if possible. Use method parameters to pass the info to your methods instead and use the return value to get info.
10. NIO is often simpler to use which is why I use it in the below code.
11. Always specify the type parameters, if you possible, instead of using raw types.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    //reads textfile into list
    static List<Entry> readPhonebook(Path path) throws Exception {
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
            return lines.map(line -> line.split("\\s", 4))
                    .filter(array -> array.length == 4)
                    .map(array -> new Entry(array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3]))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }

    //prints list to file
    static void listToFile(Path path, List<Entry> entries) throws Exception {
        try (BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(path)) {
            for (Entry entry : entries) {
                bw.append(entry.first).append('\t')
                        .append(entry.last).append('\t')
                        .append(entry.number).append('\t')
                        .append(entry.notes);
                bw.newLine();
            }
        }
    }

    // adds entry to the file
    static void appendEntryToFile(Path path, Entry entry) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardOpenOption.APPEND)) {
            bw.append(entry.first).append('\t')
                    .append(entry.last).append('\t')
                    .append(entry.number).append('\t')
                    .append(entry.notes);
            bw.newLine();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ...

        //file
        Path f = Paths.get("phonebook.txt");

        ...

        //more table stuff
        TableView<Entry> table = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Entry, String> firstcol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        firstcol.setMinWidth(100);
        firstcol.setCellValueFactory(cd -> new SimpleStringProperty(cd.getValue().first));
        TableColumn<Entry, String> lastcol = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lastcol.setMinWidth(100);
        lastcol.setCellValueFactory(cd -> new SimpleStringProperty(cd.getValue().last));
        TableColumn<Entry, String> numcol = new TableColumn<>("Number");
        numcol.setMinWidth(100);
        numcol.setCellValueFactory(cd -> new SimpleStringProperty(cd.getValue().number));
        TableColumn<Entry, String> notescol = new TableColumn<>("Notes");
        notescol.setMinWidth(100);
        notescol.setCellValueFactory(cd -> new SimpleStringProperty(cd.getValue().notes));
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstcol, lastcol, numcol, notescol);

        ...

        table.getItems().setAll(readPhonebook(f));

        ...

        //saves info and makes textfields not editable and shows array in gui
        btnEnt.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                String stfirst = null;
                if (tffirst.getText() != null) {
                    stfirst = tffirst.getText();
                }
                String stlast = null;
                if (tflast.getText() != null) {
                    stlast = tflast.getText();
                }
                String stnumber = null;
                if (tfnumber.getText() != null) {
                    stnumber = tfnumber.getText();
                }
                String stnotes = null;
                if (tfnotes.getText() != null) {
                    stnotes = tfnotes.getText();
                }
                Entry newEntry = new Entry(stfirst, stlast, stnumber, stnotes);
                table.getItems().add(newEntry);
                try {
                    appendEntryToFile(f, newEntry);
                } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error: File not saved.");
                }
                ...
            }
        });

    }

}

class Entry {

    public String first, last, number, notes;

    public Entry(String stfirst, String stlast, String stnumber, String stnotes) {
        first = stfirst;
        last = stlast;
        number = stnumber;
        notes = stnotes;
    }
}
```